# CSS Div Dynamic Inner Width Height

Tags: html, css

My clear expected output is like this:
[outer and inner div plan](https://image.ibb.co/ewZuy6/chart.png)

`Outer div` has `fixed width and height` but inner needs to have `dynamic 100%` *related to other inners*. Tried many possibilities with position *absolute, relative width, height auto and 100%* but couldn't achieve the exact result. I'm sure that there is a simple and clean way to do it with **CSS3**.

Div side:

```
<div class="window">
    <div class="titlebar">
        <div class="title">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll_right"></div>
    <div class="window_inner"></div>
    <div class="scroll_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Style side:

```
    .window {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: relative;
    }

    .titlebar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .scroll_right {
        position: absolute;
        float: right;
        width: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .window_inner {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .scroll_bottom {
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code here.

Comment: Welcome to the world of coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many corrections required in your code for your desired result. I have tried adding few of them to give you an idea.

1. remove `position:absolute;` from your divs. Because you want them to position relative to other divs.
2. remove `float:right;` from your center div.

Go through the updated code.

```css
    .window {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: relative;
    }

    .title{
       color: #ddd;
     }

    .titlebar {
        top: 0;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .scroll_right {
        float: right;
        width: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .window_inner {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .scroll_bottom {
        background-color: black;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="window">
    <div class="titlebar">
        <div class="title">Vertically Centered Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll_right">
        <div class="scroll_top"></div>
        <div class="r_middle"></div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="window_inner"> </div>
    <div class="scroll_bottom">
        <div class="scroll_left"></div>
        <div class="b_middle"></div>
        <div class="scroll_right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit : added `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to vertically align items in `.titlebar`**

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you very much. Doesn't pos absolute help us to put elements related with relative outer? Then what's the point of using pos absolute for anywhere?

Comment: position absolute means its not relative to the position of any other element of same hierarchy.  Also, accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: With your solution is there way to vertically center the title text? Because I was using pos relative and translateY for it before?

Comment: And I think also translateY is not a good solution for centering a simple text

Comment: please check the updated solution for vertical center .titlebar

Comment: Happy to help. Accept it as answer so that others can also get benefited from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
OuterDiv{
position :relativel
}
InnerDiv{
position :absolute
}
```

And you can read about flexible box that will help you.

To make the div more flexible

Comment: I think you mean flex grow but with floats I had problems. I'm adding sample code now.

Comment: And with flex I think I would have browser support problem. But I would be happy if you can share your sample also.

Answer (score 0):

In scroll_bottom change the position from abs to rela

And when you use position properties prefer to use flexbox Than float that will be more efficient