# CSS Dynamic Div Size Solution

Tags: html, css

Inner divs need to **resize related** to the outer. But in the result, **outer div's border** is *smaller* than the inners total height. Also **scroll middles** are expected to resize *100% auto* related to `left, right, top and bottom`. But they are resizing related to the outer div. What is the problem here? And do you think there is a better solution for this implementation?

```css
        body {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .window {
            width: 550px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: yellow;
            position: relative;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }

        .titlebar {
            top: 0;
            background-color: black;
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .title {
            color: white;
        }

        .scroll_right {
            float: right;
            width: 20px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .window_inner {
            background-color: red;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .scroll_bottom {
            background-color: black;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .rtop {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .rmid {
            height: 100%;
            width: 20px;
            background-color: yellowgreen;
        }

        .rbot {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .bleft {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: pink;
            float: left;
        }

        .bmid {
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: yellowgreen;
            float: left;
        }

        .bright {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: pink;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="window">
        <div class="titlebar">
            <div class="title">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll_right">
            <div class="rtop"></div>
            <div class="rmid"> </div>
            <div class="rbot"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="window_inner"></div>
        <div class="scroll_bottom">
            <div class="bleft"></div>
            <div class="bmid"> </div>
            <div class="bright"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to guess what's the expected result...

Comment: In your first try https://stackoverflow.com/q/46989165/1427878 you at least half-way made an effort of explaining what you want ...

Comment: I think you should stick to one problem at one time and try to understand how css position and sizes work. You are making very basic errors in your code. you have set your parent height to 400px and then you are adding inner divs, two with height 20px each and one with height 100%. This total will result in 100% + 40px and hence your inner blocks are more in height than your parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, I could not completely understand your question but if I am right, you need some logic with css3 `calc()` rule in your middle divs. Please check my below code for reference.

```css
 body {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .window {
            width: 550px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: yellow;
            position: relative;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }

        .titlebar {
            top: 0;
            background-color: black;
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .title {
            color: white;
        }

        .scroll_right {
            float: right;
            width: 20px;
            height: calc(100% - 40px);
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .window_inner {
            background-color: red;
            width: calc(100% - 20px);
            height: calc(100% - 40px);
        }

        .scroll_bottom {
            background-color: black;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .rtop {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .rmid {
            height: calc(100% - 40px);
            width: 20px;
            background-color: yellowgreen;
        }

        .rbot {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .bleft {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: pink;
            float: left;
        }

        .bmid {
            height: 20px;
            width: calc(100% - 40px);
            background-color: yellowgreen;
            float: left;
        }

        .bright {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: pink;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="window">
        <div class="titlebar">
            <div class="title">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll_right">
            <div class="rtop"></div>
            <div class="rmid"> </div>
            <div class="rbot"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="window_inner"></div>
        <div class="scroll_bottom">
            <div class="bleft"></div>
            <div class="bmid"> </div>
            <div class="bright"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this help

Comment: definitely if it helped.

Comment: No I won't get the -2 points and even you should not feel bad about negative votes. Its just helping us improve ourselves. I think you should check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: w3schools.com and for some advance tweeks Envato TutsPlus